# Using one variable for different classes with same methods

Tags: c++, qt

I have set of two windows created in qt designer (`win1`, `win2`) with objects of the same name. I would like to create and operate only on the one depending from the input data (`use_1`).

I can do it like that:

```
if ( use_1 )
    ui_win1->setupUi();
else
    ui_win2->setupUi();

// (...)
if ( use_1 )
    ui_win1->comboBox->clear();
else
    ui_win2->comboBox->clear();
```

and so on for all common methods I'm going to use.

Is there a more clever way to do that?

I was reading about `std::variant` and `QVariant` but it seems it's not what I am looking for.

Comment: Did you consider doing simply `auto current_win=use_1 ? ui_win1:ui_win2;` once and then using `current_win` everywhere else? Maybe even `auto &current_win`.

Comment: Good point but what in case it's a class and I would like to use it as a private variable?

Comment: Classes are not variables. This is what templates are for.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just

```
WhatewerBaseWindowType *activeWindow;

if ( use_1 )
    activeWindow = ui_win1;
else
    activeWindow =  ui_win2;

activeWindow->setupUi();
activeWindow->comboBox->clear();
// ...
```

I assume that they have some kind of base class, cause why would they have all common methods otherwise

Answer (score 0):

what about wrapping those both and defining methods to deal with it...

it actually like moving all the logic you have now inside a wrapper class.

```
class Wrapper
{
...
}
```

and some methods like

```
void wrapper::clear(bool use)
{
    if( use_1 )
        ui_win1.clear();
    else
        ui_win2.clear();
}
```

at the end you just need to call

```
myWrapper.clear(use_1);
myWrapper.init(use_1);
```

etc etc

option 2: instead of the wrapper, write a function that returns a ref to the window you want to control and trigger that using that value

like:

```
QWidget& MainWindow::getWin(bool x)
{
    if(x)
    {
        return  ui_win1;
    }
    else
    {
        return ui_win2;
    }
}
```

and in the code you do

```
this->getWin(use_1).clear();
this->getWin(use_1).setupUi();
```

etc etc

Comment: No need to call every method with `use_1`. The `Wrapper` class can have a bool field for it and set it only once in the constructor.

Comment: am not aware when use_1 is changing its value..... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: To me the op's context kind of implies that you set one window and then call its methods consecutively

Comment: @Expurple maybe you r right, for me is not explicit whether use_1 is a value that never changes at  runtime... maybe after clarification we can edit my post and remove the bool parameter...

Comment: If `use_1` changes from time to time, nothing stops us from changing it as a public bool `Wrapper` field and not as a separate variable. Still no need to pass it as a parameter every time :)